# Getting undocumented P_TRANSTATEn from PayPal

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, payflowpro

I'm querying for transaction status history and in the response from PayPal I'm getting an unknown P_TRANSTATEn value of 0. Here's a sample from the end of the response (the front part isn't relevant to this)

```
&P_RESULT1=23&P_TENDER1=C&P_AMT1=30.00&P_TRANSTATE1=0
```

Can anyone shed some light on this?

EDIT: According to their documentation that I found, these are the expected codes:

```
P_TRANSTATEn TRANS_STATE of the particular payment.
 1: error 
 6: settlement pending 
 7: settlement in progress 
 8: settlement completed/successfully 
 11: settlement failed 
 14: settlement incomplete
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, seems 0 is the status assigned to transactions when the recurring profile is cancelled.